# Refresh a Div using data from data base using ajax

Tags: jquery

I have this project where I have change the images inside a slideshow without refreshing the page. I've spent more then 4 hours googling for tutorials in vain.

I'm new with ajax and jquery and i want something to start with.

I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to set the `src` attribute of any `img` tag:

```
$('#imgid').attr('src','new/path/to/image.jpg');
```

Alternatively, perhaps [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is what you need -- it performs an AJAX request on an HTML document or fragment and automatically adds it to the DOM element you selected. For instance:

```
$('#box1').load('images/photo.html')
```

Will add the file at that URL into the DOM element with ID "box1".

Comment: i'm sorry but load is used for loading content from a html page not for images, isn't it?

Comment: @Amson True, but there's no reason you can't load an HTML fragment that contains only an `<img>` tag. Updated my answer with a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer should solve your query, 
However if you are concerned with cacheing the images as the above technique might not resolve the images in time. try using this

The data received from the ajax call is  a JSON object of the form

```
data:
{
    "title":"Heart of Baikal",
     "url":"http://abc.net/4.jpg"
}
```

**quick explaination of what the code does**:

1. On getting the data from the ajax call a javascript object is created and pushed in a array/list.
2. the hover function simply displays the image when you hover over the target (defined with class show here)

the link here gives a sample working [model](http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/bfJFX/):

```
$.ajax({
   //...add other properties of the ajax call here
   success: function(data) {
        var preloadedImages = [];
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            var tempImage = new Image();
            tempImage.src = item.url;
            preloadedImages.push(tempImage);
        });
        $(".show").hover(function() {
            //mouseover
            $.each(preloadedImages, function(index, item) {
                $("<img>").attr({
                    src: item.src
                }).appendTo("#ajax-json");
            });
        }, function() {
            //mouse out
            $("#ajax-json").empty();
        });

    },

    error: function(error) {
        alert("there was an error");
    },
    dataType: "json"
 });
```